# How can I make document field = map in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How do i make a document field = map(object)?

My code now, just an example:

---

name, age and user number from html input

on a buttons click do this:

```
var nameInput
var ageInput
var userNumberInput
db.collection("users").doc("all_users").set({
 userNumberInput: {
  name: nameInput,
  age: ageInput
}
});
```

My code does this:

```
collection --> document  --> field
users      --> all_users --> userNumberInput{name: kasper, age: 17} userNumberInput{name: caroline, age: 20}
```

---

I want my code to do this, example:

```
collection --> document  --> field
users      --> all_users --> user1{name: kasper, age: 17} user2{name: caroline, age: 20}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time following your question.  Where do your "user1" and "user2" strings come from?  Are you putting them all in at the same time?

Comment: @DougStevenson yeah, sorry. It comes from the userNumberInput, so in this example the user just writes the "user1" or "user2" strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure if I quite understood your question correctly, but I assume you want they value of your variable "userNumberInput" to be the key and not the actual string "userNumberInput"

If you use ES6 then you can use the feature of ComputedPropertyName.

```
var nameInput
var ageInput
var userNumberInput
db.collection("users").doc("all_users").set({
 [userNumberInput]: {
  name: nameInput,
  age: ageInput
}
});
```

if not then you can do it in the old fashion way

```
var nameInput
var ageInput
var userNumberInput
let obj = {}
obj[userNumberInput] = {
  name: nameInput,
  age: ageInput
}
db.collection("users").doc("all_users").set(obj);
```

Comment: yes, I had tried the same but i had written userNumberInput without [] around. So that was the answer i was searching for. Because when I do my code it just makes the map field name to the variable name. So thanks, but what does the [] do? :)

Comment: I have now made my code the the answer you gave here. It works, but when I have added one user through my form on my html page, it works. But when I already have on user in (users --> all_users -->). And I add one more through the form, it just rewrites the already user under (users --> all_users -->). How to do so it addes a new map field, instead of rewriting the already existing user?

Comment: anwser to my own 2 comment, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_documentjust after .set({}); add { merge: true } => .set({ }, { merge: true });

Comment: [] is a feature named Computed Property Name,  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names